# How to prevent losing the mouse cursor when dragging an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I am building an interactive SVG graph (using Javascript and SVG, not Raphael or JQuery). The user clicks on a  element and drags it to an different location on the screen. This is repeated with other elements. When finished, he clicks a button and submits the X,Y changes to a call back script that processes them.
This works (Safari, IE), but often the mousetracking is lost, leading to extra clicking and dragging. It seems to happen more often when the graphic is more complex. I have two questions: a. what causes the script to lose the tracking and b. is there a way to make the process more robust?

Here is the code that handles the selection and movement of the SVG:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var selectedElement = 0;
    var currentX = 0;
    var currentY = 0;
    var currentMatrix = 0;
    var paramHistory = "";

    function selectElement(evt) {
      selectedElement = evt.target;
      currentID = selectedElement.id;
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
      currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7,-1).split(' ');
      for(var i=0; i<currentMatrix.length; i++) {
        currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
      }
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deselectElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(evt)");
    }

    function moveElement(evt) {
      var dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
      var dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
      currentMatrix[4] += dx;
      currentMatrix[5] += dy;

      absX = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "x") + "|" + currentMatrix[4];
      absY = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "y") + "|" + currentMatrix[5];

      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")");
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
    }

    function deselectElement(evt) {
      if(selectedElement != 0){
          paramHistory += "||" + currentID + "|" + absX + "|" + absY;
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
          selectedElement = 0;
          }
        }
       ]]> </script>
```

The SVG elements are defined as follows (most of the elements have fill-patternes rather than colors):

```
<rect id="123456789" class="draggable" x="1104" y="225" width="98" height="190"  fill="red" stroke = "#000000"  fill-opacity="0.7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>
```

(JS inspired by Peter Collingridge)
HE

Answer (score 0):

Register the mousemove, mouseup and mouseout(*edit: no mouseout!*) Event on the outermost svg element. Set pointer-events to none on the dragged Element. Make sure to have a background element which cover the whole svg, to realy capture all mouse events.

### Edit 1: like so...

```js
var selectedElement = 0;
var currentX = 0;
var currentY = 0;
var currentMatrix = 0;
var paramHistory = "";


function selectElement(evt) {
  selectedElement = evt.target;
  currentID = selectedElement.id;
  currentX = evt.clientX;
  currentY = evt.clientY;
  currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7, -1).split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < currentMatrix.length; i++) {
    currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
  }
  selectedElement.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none")
  outerSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
  outerSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(evt)");
}

function moveElement(evt) {
  var dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
  var dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
  currentMatrix[4] += dx;
  currentMatrix[5] += dy;

  absX = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "x") + "|" + currentMatrix[4];
  absY = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "y") + "|" + currentMatrix[5];

  selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")");
  currentX = evt.clientX;
  currentY = evt.clientY;
}

function deselectElement(evt) {
  if (selectedElement != 0) {
    selectedElement.setAttribute("pointer-events", "all")
    paramHistory += "||" + currentID + "|" + absX + "|" + absY;
    outerSVG.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
    outerSVG.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
    selectedElement = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="outerSVG" width="100%" height="400px">

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500px" height="400px" fill="none" pointer-events="fill" />
  <rect id="123456789" class="draggable" x="104" y="35" width="98" height="190" fill="red" stroke="#000000" fill-opacity="0.7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)" />
  <rect id="123456729" class="draggable" x="204" y="25" width="123" height="70" fill="green" stroke="#000000" fill-opacity="0.7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: One more question: does this mean I have to include all draggable elements within the the 'outer' rect (in your modification, the one with attribute 'pointer-elements="fill")? And keep the other elements (text, static elements etc) outside?

Comment: no, when you add the event listener to the outermost svg element, everything inside acts as a target for your mosemove. This is exactly what we want. the rect with pointer-events="fill" only acts as a last resort to catch all mouse events on spots where there are no other elements.